# Projects using this stage in odoo 10 is disappeared?

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10

In odoo 10 something is missing.

In odoo 9.0 you can specify the projects that share the same stages in the stage editing page as following:

[image]

But this does not exist in Odoo 10.0.

How do I get this to appear?

Answer (score -1):

Try enable developer mode, they appear

Comment: Please explain your answer more (e.g. how to do it)